# DHF and CPF/Alert configuration

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf, ml-gradle

I am using DHF and I have a usecase where I need to configure `alerts` for my `final db`. I am configuring via `gradle` both the `cpf` which is required by `alerts` and `alerts`. In my configuration, how can I tell that a given `cpf` is enabled only for my `final` DB ?

I understand I can set my `Domain` to be `collection` that is present in my `final` db, but still the `CPF` will be enabled in both `staging` and `final` db.. and also my `delete's` in `staging` will be slow..

Comment: CPF is configured on a per-database level. Are you asking how to get ml-gradle to deploy your CPF config to final but not staging?

Comment: Yes I want to deploy cpf only in final DB

Comment: @Ravi In the latest DHF release (4.0), staging and final have separate modules and trigger databases. Would that solve your problem?